# How to check difference for data stored in same column in R?

Tags: r, time, multiple-columns

I have a dataset with a column called Person and a column Time. The combination of these columns indicate at which time an employee completed a task. A person can complete multiple tasks on one day. I want to know what the difference between completion of two following tasks from the same person is and I want to store this data in another column. For sure I have to add a new column, but is this doable with one code? Or should I make a column first that stores the time of the next task completed by the same person? Any tips on how to do this?

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please read [ask] and [mcve]! At the current state your question is off-topic for SO.

Answer (score 0):

I would tackle this using the dplyr package (though I am sure an equivalent solution exists using the data.table package).

- Create a tibble (data frame) with the two columns, Person and Time.
- Group the data by Person, and sort the data by Time. This will keep your data grouped by individual people, with each person's tasks in time order.
- Then I would use the dplyr mutate command to create a 'TimeSinceLastTask' column. The equation you will need to do this needs to use the dplyr lead (or lag) functions to look up the following (or previous) result to subtract from the current value in Time.

If you are using times, I'd strongly recommend the use of lubridate to do your time difference calculations (makes it less messy).

I hope that makes sense. Not near an R terminal so can't safely create you a reprex that works (ie. I could guess but my blind coding never works first time!)

Hope that helps.

Andrew

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help! With the lead function the last row of a person is compared with the first row of another person. Do you know how I can avoid this? I would like it to show NA.

Comment: You can change your dplyr::mutate statement for TimeSinceLastTask to use dplyr::if_else. You want to compare that the person is the same - if TRUE, then calculate the difference. If FALSE, then use 0 or a negative number. I'd avoid NA as otherwise if you try to subtract with NA you will need to check for NA in the FALSE statement.

Comment: If you must have NAs in your final result then I'd do a substitution of 0 (or your negative value) at the end.